# Firefox doens't open local addesses

Tags: firefox

I have a *network* server named **acesso** and I access it in IE by: `http://acesso/caiautorizacao/` for exemple...

But if I try this url on firefox, it redirects to `www.acesso.com/caiautorizacao`.

May it can be a configuration problem? Maybe changing some value of **about:config** ??

Edit: Google Chorme shows 404 error in this same url.

Edit[2]: My firefox version is 7.0.1 on a Windows 7 Home Premium x86.

Comment: You have a local server - defined in your host-file? Or it's in your domain and IE auto-completes the domain?

Comment: Nope. IE access exactly as I posted above. What is host-file ?

Comment: What do you mean "local server" ?

Comment: Oh God, do I mistook you? I mean local server not as 127.0.0.1, it's not in my machine, it's in my network, in other machine. Sorry if this' not clear !!

Comment: That explains why user973254 misunderstood. Now, if it's in your network, why can IE find it, and FF not? Maybe your network as a domain name in the `Connection-specific DNS Suffix` which IE picks up and FF does not? Do an `ipconfig /all` in your command prompt? Does a `ping acesso` work? Does a `nslookup acesso` work? Can you connect to the IP address with IE and with FF?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake =/ Yes, `ping` reaches 'acesso' server as `nslookup` too. FF access using IP address `http://172.25.109.250/caiautorizacao/` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433364). People are asking for it to be resolved, but so far no good.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the value of both `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` and `keyword.enabled` to `false` from `about:config`

Comment: Sorry there are two config properties that you have to change (I have updated my answer). I tried it and it works.

Comment: Which version of FF do you have?

Comment: The last one: **7.0.1**.

Comment: This time I tried on FF 7 and it worked fine. You have to change both `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` and `keyword.enabled` to `false`.

Comment: Damn, here doesn't worked.. Do you edited hosts file ?

Comment: No, I did not edit the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
127.0.0.1    acesso
```

to your `hosts` file

Comment: ` %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\ ` but you need administrators privileges to be able to edit it.

Comment: I've changed but don't worked. I think that is someting on IE cause I realize that Google Chrome return 404 error on this url. =s

Comment: it should work, remove leading 'http://' and try just `acesso`

Comment: No, it all redirects to `www.acesso.com` !! >|

Comment: Vote up for you cause my explanation wasn't right. Thank you for your help!